# alert/notification in locked screen

Tags: iphone, notifications, alert, locked

I want to do a simple **alert** as per given time from the application,alert is also show if phone is locked. and when press ok then go to application view(if phone is locked). if we can not navigate to the application **programmatically**, then i can do manually do the screen unlock. but when i do the unlock the application should open. so is there any way to do like this?

Yes i know the i can do it with local notification but my question is : when i click "View detail" or any other button + my phone is locked - so can i go to my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your are looking for Local Notifications see [About Local Notifications and Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Yes i know the i can do it with local notification but my question is : when i click "View detail" or any other button + my phone is locked - so can i go to my app.

Comment: I am not sure if you mean this, but in iOS 5 this works by sliding the icon of the notification on the lock screen in stead of the unlock slider itself, this will open up your app after unlocking

Comment: ya that things happen , i just refer [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588964/iphone-local-notification-in-simulator