# How to run a fresh install of the application every time unit tests are run?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xctest

I've setup some `XCTest` unit tests for my application and would like every time I run tests for it to run in a brand new install of the application.  Currently when I run subsequent tests it runs the tests in the same application that was run before which has a lot of state information already changed by the previous tests.

Is there a way to indicate that when you run unit tests that it should run the tests on a fresh version of your application?

Comment: @SteveRosenberg Clean just cleans your 'build' directory, it doesn't uninstall apps.

Answer (score 31):

Maybe this works, but only for Simulator.

In `Product` > `Scheme` > `Edit Scheme...`

[image]

`xcrun simctl` is command line utility to control the iOS Simulator.
This uninstalls `com.yourcompany.AppName` application from **booted** simulator before running tests.

I don't know how to do like this for real device :(

Comment: One could use `ios-deploy` in the same way perhaps?

Comment: The way to use this in-between tests is to run it in a yml file or shell within Jenkins

Comment: if i want only uninstallation for ui tests how can i do that? i dont want in unit tests.

Comment: @LaserHawk could you elaborate more? Perhaps in a separate answer?

Comment: This still does not work for device.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to @rintaro's answer, if you set *"Provide build settings from"* to your app, you can add a generic command, which will keep working when your bundle id changes:

```
xcrun simctl uninstall booted ${PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? What have you tried? What makes you so certain this doesn't work?