# Using Xcode7's UI tests to create app screenshots for the App Store

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, ios9, xcode-ui-testing

Every time we change something in the UI, we have to manually prepare and take 375 (= 5 screenshots * 5 device types * 15 languages) screenshots for iTunes Connect's listing.

I'm trying to "exploit" iOS 9's new UI testing to automatically prepare and take these screenshots for each language. This should save a huge amount of time and provide a better experience to our users, because we didn't update the screenshots frequently due to the hard work involved.

I couldn't find much help on the internet, probably because this feature is too fresh. So here are two essential questions, hopefully we can find a way to make it happen.

1. Is it possible to save a screenshot to disk through the UI testing API?
2. Is it possible to have a clean install for a XCTestCase?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't completely related to Xcode 7, but you can automate screenshot taking with [snapshot](https://github.com/KrauseFx/snapshot).

Comment: Doesn't answer the UI tests API questions, but I'll accept because it solves the problem perfectly and maybe even in a better way.

Comment: @rounak I saw that yesterday when looking at snapshot :)

Comment: @Kof I've implemented screenshot taking for Xcode7 UI tests. Screenshots are captured by the app and passed to the test via sockets, requires adding a framework to the app. The code is here: https://github.com/zmeyc/UITestUtils

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can create screenshots using the Xcode UI Testing.

- Create a custom scheme for your tests (optional but recommended).
- Use CLI(terminal) to run the tests. Something like this:

> ```
> xcodebuild -workspace App.xcworkspace \
>      -scheme "SchemeName" \
>            -sdk iphonesimulator \
>            -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=9.0' 
>            test
> ```

Once you are done with this, to generate screenshots, add the path to where you want the screenshots, like this:

> ```
> xcodebuild -workspace App.xcworkspace \
>  -scheme "SchemeName" \
>        -sdk iphonesimulator \
>        -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=9.0'
>        -derivedDataPath './output'
>        test
> ```

./output will tell Xcode to take screenshots for every test.
You can find this in detail [here](https://krausefx.com/blog/run-xcode-7-ui-tests-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Is it possible to save a screenshot to disk through the UI testing API?

You can manually save them (through the "open in preview" button), but I do not know of an API to collect them during the tests. File a radar! (https://bugreport.apple.com)

> 2. Is it possible to have a clean install for a XCTestCase?

I don't know of a way to actually reinstall your app for every `XCTestCase`, but you can [uninstall it before running *all* of your tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26190660/2446155), or you can [use the `setUp` class method or instance method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21040654/2446155) on `XCTestCase` to ensure that your app is in a fresh state before your tests are run (ex. reset user defaults, etc).

Comment: About #2, how do I reset user defaults / documents dir on the `setUp`? Couldn't find anything related in XCUIApplication reference.

Comment: @Kof: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32351149/how-do-i-reset-the-application-data-after-each-test-with-xcode-7-ui-testing , and here http://www.adamkaump.com/thoughts/uitests

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way I found to do this so far: [Automating App Store localized screenshots with XCTest and Xcode Test Plan](https://benoitpasquier.com/automating-appstore-localized-screenshot-xctest/)

To sum it up (and try to make sure this answer doesn't suffer from link rot in the future), you should create a Test Plan that goes through the screens in your app you want to screenshot and include code similar to the following to take the screenshots:

```swift
class AppStoreScreenshotTests: XCTestCase {

    var app : XCUIApplication!

    override func setUpWithError() throws {
        continueAfterFailure = false
        self.app = XCUIApplication()
    }
    
    override func tearDownWithError() throws {
        self.app = nil
    }

    func testSearchJourney() {
        self.app.launch()

        // moving to search tab
        app.buttons[AccessibilityIdentifiers.searchTab.rawValue].tap()
        
        // wait for screen to be fully displayed within 5sec
        XCTAssertTrue(app.buttons[AccessibilityIdentifiers.searchButton.rawValue].waitForExistence(timeout: 5))
        
        // take a screenshot of the search page
        attachScreenshot(name: "search-form")
    }

    private func attachScreenshot(name: String) {
        let screenshot = app.windows.firstMatch.screenshot()
        let attachment = XCTAttachment(screenshot: screenshot)
        attachment.name = name
        attachment.lifetime = .keepAlways
        add(attachment)
    }
```

Then you can automate creation and extraction of screenshots with a shell script that executes the test with `xcodebuild test` and use `xcparse` to export them into a separate folder:

```bash
xcparse screenshots --os --model --test-plan-config /path/to/Test.xcresult /path/to/outputDirectory
```

Personally I prefer this approach rather than using Fastlane.