# `react-native run-ios` returns Error: Could not find iPhone X simulator

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator, react-native-ios

whenever I run `react-native run-ios`, I get

```
Could not find iPhone X simulator

Error: Could not find iPhone X simulator
    at resolve (calendarPractice/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:149:13)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at runOnSimulator (calendarPractice/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:134:10)
    at Object.runIOS [as func] (calendarPractice/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:106:12)
    at Promise.resolve.then (calendarPractice/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cliEntry.js:117:22)
```

however, when I run on Xcode, it works fine

```
{
  "devicetypes" : [
    {
      "name" : "iPhone 4s",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPhone 4s.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPhone 5",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPhone 5.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPhone 5s",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPhone 5s.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPhone 6",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPhone 6.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPhone 6 Plus",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPhone 6 Plus.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6-Plus"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPhone 6s",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPhone 6s.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6s"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPhone 6s Plus",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPhone 6s Plus.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6s-Plus"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPhone 7",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPhone 7.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-7"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPhone 7 Plus",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPhone 7 Plus.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-7-Plus"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPhone 8",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPhone 8.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-8"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPhone 8 Plus",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPhone 8 Plus.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-8-Plus"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPhone SE",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPhone SE.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-SE"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPhone X",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPhone X.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-X"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPhone Xs",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPhone Xs.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-XS"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPhone Xs Max",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPhone Xs Max.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-XS-Max"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPhone Xʀ",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPhone Xʀ.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-XR"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPad 2",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPad 2.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPad Retina",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPad Retina.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Retina"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPad Air",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPad Air.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPad Air 2",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPad Air 2.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air-2"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPad (5th generation)",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPad (5th generation).simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad--5th-generation-"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPad Pro (9.7-inch)",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPad Pro (9.7-inch).simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--9-7-inch-"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPad Pro (12.9-inch)",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPad Pro (12.9-inch).simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation)",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation).simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--12-9-inch---2nd-generation-"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPad Pro (10.5-inch)",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPad Pro (10.5-inch).simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--10-5-inch-"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPad (6th generation)",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPad (6th generation).simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad--6th-generation-"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPad Pro (11-inch)",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPad Pro (11-inch).simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--11-inch-"
    },
    {
      "name" : "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation)",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation).simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Pro--12-9-inch---3rd-generation-"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Apple TV",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/AppleTVOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/Apple TV.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-TV-1080p"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Apple TV 4K",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/AppleTVOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/Apple TV 4K.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-TV-4K-4K"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Apple TV 4K (at 1080p)",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/AppleTVOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/Apple TV 4K (at 1080p).simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-TV-4K-1080p"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Apple Watch - 38mm",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/WatchOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/Apple Watch - 38mm.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-38mm"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Apple Watch - 42mm",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/WatchOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/Apple Watch - 42mm.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-42mm"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Apple Watch Series 2 - 38mm",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/WatchOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/Apple Watch Series 2 - 38mm.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-2-38mm"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Apple Watch Series 2 - 42mm",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/WatchOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/Apple Watch Series 2 - 42mm.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-2-42mm"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Apple Watch Series 3 - 38mm",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/WatchOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/Apple Watch Series 3 - 38mm.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-3-38mm"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Apple Watch Series 3 - 42mm",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/WatchOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/Apple Watch Series 3 - 42mm.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-3-42mm"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Apple Watch Series 4 - 40mm",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/WatchOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/Apple Watch Series 4 - 40mm.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-4-40mm"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Apple Watch Series 4 - 44mm",
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/WatchOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/DeviceTypes\/Apple Watch Series 4 - 44mm.simdevicetype",
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Apple-Watch-Series-4-44mm"
    }
  ],
  "runtimes" : [
    {
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/iPhoneOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/Runtimes\/iOS.simruntime",
      "availabilityError" : "",
      "buildversion" : "16B91",
      "availability" : "(available)",
      "isAvailable" : true,
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-1",
      "version" : "12.1",
      "name" : "iOS 12.1"
    },
    {
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/AppleTVOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/Runtimes\/tvOS.simruntime",
      "availabilityError" : "",
      "buildversion" : "16J602",
      "availability" : "(available)",
      "isAvailable" : true,
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS-12-1",
      "version" : "12.1",
      "name" : "tvOS 12.1"
    },
    {
      "bundlePath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/Developer\/Platforms\/WatchOS.platform\/Developer\/Library\/CoreSimulator\/Profiles\/Runtimes\/watchOS.simruntime",
      "availabilityError" : "",
      "buildversion" : "16R591",
      "availability" : "(available)",
      "isAvailable" : true,
      "identifier" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-5-1",
      "version" : "5.1",
      "name" : "watchOS 5.1"
    }
  ],
  "devices" : {
    "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.watchOS-5-1" : [
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "Apple Watch Series 2 - 38mm",
        "udid" : "01AFDEF7-63B6-465C-A02A-44EE4A07EABA",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "Apple Watch Series 2 - 42mm",
        "udid" : "BE62C985-DEE2-46EC-8962-A582D537EEE0",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "Apple Watch Series 3 - 38mm",
        "udid" : "078BF157-30FA-41D1-94FA-6B1686E03085",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "Apple Watch Series 3 - 42mm",
        "udid" : "E4CE652E-0185-4C59-B965-BED5FCEE7C76",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "Apple Watch Series 4 - 40mm",
        "udid" : "6621323A-A9DE-4BCB-AC97-54C8C33B0158",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "Apple Watch Series 4 - 44mm",
        "udid" : "D89037A3-66A0-43C1-90BA-E7C76CA0D724",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      }
    ],
    "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS-12-1" : [
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "Apple TV",
        "udid" : "AFAA21B8-BD4A-45EA-B0FF-E9915FE9B926",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "Apple TV 4K",
        "udid" : "EBB88F2E-CFFE-4981-A736-7A7C0B85643D",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "Apple TV 4K (at 1080p)",
        "udid" : "F0B73E8A-986E-447E-B37A-2F46096DEFF6",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      }
    ],
    "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-1" : [
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPhone 5s",
        "udid" : "F870B7FA-6DDA-4336-89AD-68A402844188",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPhone 5s",
        "udid" : "6627ADE5-F8C1-4AE5-BD6F-3AEDDC0B7B63",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPhone 6",
        "udid" : "05574997-ACAD-40CA-A3D7-5624D53F00FA",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPhone 6 Plus",
        "udid" : "93237078-CA6D-4F97-93F9-779809700018",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPhone 6s",
        "udid" : "9B50FE18-4F49-4EA4-80F0-DF498A667D33",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPhone 6s Plus",
        "udid" : "D4640B6D-97DC-4CA1-BE63-C5403159A3D4",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPhone 7",
        "udid" : "6E9EEC00-3291-42B4-B04A-BA3487F9CD5F",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPhone 7 Plus",
        "udid" : "6DA1C3CF-1D1F-4DEF-9B74-2C40D5FB5881",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPhone 8",
        "udid" : "E19386B9-469A-450B-9CD2-B4FE8687DCF9",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPhone 8 Plus",
        "udid" : "6D36DF76-8ED9-41A2-9E1A-0BA48B92C26E",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPhone SE",
        "udid" : "EE4818DF-F817-4441-8A1C-BE1B99303E10",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPhone X",
        "udid" : "85B78A8F-C32B-4493-BDD1-65ECA3F77C86",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPhone X",
        "udid" : "CA12C337-4F66-4C6C-ACE5-7F7EACCBC39A",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPhone XS",
        "udid" : "8BBCE315-2F4C-4132-8E53-28AF52401C8E",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPhone XS Max",
        "udid" : "4E77C62F-AB1F-4EDE-839B-53F70CAFC79E",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPhone XR",
        "udid" : "28D12ABE-3355-4862-960A-0FE5FFE41C7B",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPad Air",
        "udid" : "94485C88-BCEB-456A-95DC-5F8C3DA8D181",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPad Air 2",
        "udid" : "CF2C787D-A378-4AB9-B334-F7B24E94AF4D",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPad (5th generation)",
        "udid" : "DFE602A5-EC68-4585-8AB0-C045A9843D29",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPad Pro (9.7-inch)",
        "udid" : "5A3F3EAC-F788-49F1-A753-5D34A9990F0B",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPad Pro (12.9-inch)",
        "udid" : "EF6EBE34-0A85-4FF0-8A45-7BA418A0CC0C",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation)",
        "udid" : "FBA940F8-FD85-4D5E-A570-EB4F3A56E1F9",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPad Pro (10.5-inch)",
        "udid" : "8AE4AAED-ECE0-4984-9679-8D3022064692",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPad (6th generation)",
        "udid" : "1121363D-EF49-4AC0-9E46-5C30318A24A2",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPad Pro (11-inch)",
        "udid" : "038FECC0-8711-46E3-B601-8F88F2F4AD7D",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      },
      {
        "availability" : "(available)",
        "state" : "Shutdown",
        "isAvailable" : true,
        "name" : "iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation)",
        "udid" : "12DC911F-2F45-4767-BC1A-6F1D0C8D9F3D",
        "availabilityError" : ""
      }
    ]
  },
  "pairs" : {
    "C9B69F4A-6A9D-44F3-A6BC-56BFA2F8B83F" : {
      "watch" : {
        "name" : "Apple Watch Series 4 - 44mm",
        "udid" : "D89037A3-66A0-43C1-90BA-E7C76CA0D724",
        "state" : "Shutdown"
      },
      "phone" : {
        "name" : "iPhone XS Max",
        "udid" : "4E77C62F-AB1F-4EDE-839B-53F70CAFC79E",
        "state" : "Shutdown"
      },
      "state" : "(active, disconnected)"
    },
    "5327B65F-29E7-42D0-9861-FF31428F3218" : {
      "watch" : {
        "name" : "Apple Watch Series 4 - 40mm",
        "udid" : "6621323A-A9DE-4BCB-AC97-54C8C33B0158",
        "state" : "Shutdown"
      },
      "phone" : {
        "name" : "iPhone XS",
        "udid" : "8BBCE315-2F4C-4132-8E53-28AF52401C8E",
        "state" : "Shutdown"
      },
      "state" : "(active, disconnected)"
    }
  }
```

Comment: what is your xcode version?

Comment: my xcode version is 10.1

Comment: which version react-native do you use? because some version of react-native has an issue related this problem

Comment: npmPackages:
      react: 16.6.3 => 16.6.3
      react-native: ^0.58.3 => 0.58.3

Comment: I thought this was the latest version

Comment: Could you check in node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js, is there this snippet `if (
        simulator.availability !== '(available)' &&
        simulator.isAvailable !== 'YES'
      ) {
        continue;
      }`

Comment: yes, there is that snippet!

Comment: could you run this command `xcrun simctl list --json` on your terminal and add the result to your question? So we can understand what is it going on?

Comment: Yes I just added

Comment: I answered, because it is long for comment. Please try and let me know.

Comment: Easy and fast way to resolve this issue by below script. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56920807/706888

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Edited:
I copied your devices section of your output JSON and embedded to my own `/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js`

```
function runOnSimulator(xcodeProject, args, scheme) {
return new Promise(resolve => {
    try {
        var simulators = {devices section of your json}; //Here
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("e", e);
        throw new Error('Could not parse the simulator list output');
    }

    const selectedSimulator = findMatchingSimulator(simulators, args.simulator);
    console.log("selected", selectedSimulator);
    if (!selectedSimulator) {
        throw new Error(`Could not find ${args.simulator} simulator`);
    }
    ...
```

And finally, it gave the same error as yours. So I figured out that parsing version of devices different. In your devices, version is;

```
"com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS-12-1" //for tvOS
"com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-1" // for iOS
```

but in react-native checks this version values like this(`/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js`);

```
// Making sure the version of the simulator is an iOS or tvOS (Removes Apple Watch, etc)
if (!version.startsWith('iOS') && !version.startsWith('tvOS')) {
    continue;
}
```

So react-native can not recognize.
If we change this code with this;

```
// Making sure the version of the simulator is an iOS or tvOS (Removes Apple Watch, etc)
if (!version.startsWith('com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS') && !version.startsWith('com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS')) {
    continue;
}
```

the problem was solved. I checked that with your JSON data in my computer and it worked.

Comment: Hate that this worked - anyone have a more permanent solution?

Comment: Same problem here. Is there any permanent solution to avoid nom install backroll. Downgrade to xcode 10.0?

Comment: In case anyone was running iPhone XR specifically (ie. `react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone XR'`), use the following, `react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone Xʀ'`. Using a lowercase r will not work.

Comment: The longer term fix is to await the next release of `react-native-cli`, where this is fixed https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-cli/pull/274

Comment: Permanent solution for this issue? For me it works to upgrade RN to 0.58.6

Comment: How is this the answer?!?!?!?! you don't mess with plugins like that

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. runIOS folder isn't on react-native folder in node_modules as of today. Any other fix?

Comment: @MixMasterMike i run your command but in every time just iPhone x launch :(

Comment: @MixMasterMike you can run any installed simulator with that command `react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone SE"`. For example that command will run iPhone SE simulator, which is installed on Xcode.

Comment: @OliverD unfortunately, I haven't touched my RN project since posting my comment. But did you happen to copy and paste the 2nd code? The one with the small capital R.

Comment: @sdkcy yup, that's the idea. the key is to know the exact model you're trying to target as stated [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-simulator-ios).

Answer (score 119):

To fix this error, simply reinstall project & node modules using npm

`npm install`

Then it will show a list of warnings, and to fix them use the following command:

`npm audit fix`

This should fix everything, and allow you to run iOS emulator
`react-native run-ios`

Comment: Its nothing to do with npm as it will just install or audit node modules

Comment: This fixed it for me... without doing the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Firu And yet there are at least three of us now for which this was the fix.

Comment: this didn't work for me. `react-native --version` -> `react-native-cli: 2.0.1 react-native: 0.57.7` `react-native info` -> `macOS 10.14.4 Platforms: iOS 12.2 Xcode: 10.2/10E125`

Comment: This worked for me too.. Too early. It opens up emulator but application building fails :|

Comment: Worked for me too.

Comment: imho this should be the right answer. Changing `node_modules` files should not be a valid answer. It will come back to bite you when you trash  `node_modules` folder for any reason.

Comment: Worked for me.Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for  you all. Just to clarify, I mean first step : npm install is using npm to reinstall the node modules, not reinstall npm. My apologies on the typo.

Comment: `npm audit fix`changes my react-native version to 0.59.8 from 0.57.5. Is this the solution or side affect?

Comment: @levye side effect, really troublesome by the way.

Comment: Worked, thanks!. My guess is this problem occurs when attempting to run older React Native projects.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with yarn?

Answer (score 79):

**PROBLEM**

If you try this with the latest Xcode (11), there is no iPhone X!

Run Simulator by itself, in the top menu, look under Hardware, Device, iOS 13.0.
You will see there is:

- iPhone 8
- iPhone 8 Plus
- iPhone XS
- iPhone XS Max
- iPhone XR
- ... and some iPads

When you execute `run-ios`, react-native is designed to match a requested device.

The internally hard coded default is iPhone X.

The function that tries to match the requested device is in:

`/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js`

This function is designed so you can give it a device, and an optional version number.

If the given device and version cannot be found, it will return a match using the first device in the list by default.

But... in reality, the first device is a watch, and any watch is excluded from matching, so this function will return null.

**SOLUTION 1 - Use an existing Xcode device**

Run Simulator first by itself, as described above, and make a note of which iPhone or iPad you want.

Then pass this name as an optional argument the the run-ios command line command as follows:

`react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 8"`

**SOLUTION 2 - Add New Xcode iOS Device**

According to [Xcode 11 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes):

"Xcode no longer creates every available iOS simulator device by default. Instead a set of the most commonly used devices are created. To create other devices — or multiple instances of a device — open the Devices window, select Simulators, click the + button, enter a name, and select the relevant device type and OS version. In Terminal, execute the xcrun simctl create    command, for example xcrun simctl create "My iPhone 7" "iPhone 7" iOS13.0. (49428617)"

In Xcode, you need to add a new device called "iPhone X".

Also I answered here: [React Native Issue #2328](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23282)

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved the day. Instead of manually configuring the changes this is the easiest and by far the most accurate solution in case of ios 13+. Personally this should be tagged as the accepted answer.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, along with a quick explanation of how to change the RN default from iPhone X

Comment: iOS 13.0 simulators now doesn't include every available devices except for the most used one, you need to manually create them if you want other devices (e.g iPhone 7, iPhone X). Reference is here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes

Comment: this fixed and should be the primary answer.

Comment: I simply added an iPhone X to the list of available devices directly in XCode. Now it can be found!

Comment: Yes, this is the actual reason, do not try to edit any files. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Radu Cimpian's answer tells you how to do SOLUTION #2.

Answer (score 48):

Temporary fix:

**Step 1**: Open the file `/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js`

**Step 2**: Change a line of code, from this:

```
if (!version.startsWith('iOS') && !version.startsWith('tvOS')) {
  continue;
}
```

to this:

```
if (!version.startsWith('com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS') && !version.startsWith('com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS')) {
  continue;
}
```

**Step 3**: Run `react-native run-ios` (you might need to run it twice, and don't forget to kill the Metro Bundler [the console that's running in the background] if it's running from your previous unsuccessful build!)

The problem was that after an update to Xcode - the simulator namespaces were added to the devices' versions list. The React Native build wasn't expecting these namespaces - hence the build break.

Comment: I cant find the runIOS directory. Any suggestions?

Comment: Run `react-native run-ios` with `--verbose` flag. It will indicate the file where the logic above is located.

Answer (score 37):

after update to Xcode 11 xcrun returns true or false and not YES or NO as before.

goto */node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js* and in

find

```
if (
   simulator.availability !== '(available)' &&
   simulator.isAvailable !== 'YES'
 ) {
  continue;
}
```

and change it to

```
if (
   simulator.availability !== '(available)' &&
   simulator.isAvailable !== true
 ) {
  continue;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. Found it different directory.

node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js

Comment: They changed it again (wtf) ```/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js```

Comment: I couldn't find (wtf)

Comment: too bad. Same thing here. In earlier versions of XCode, I had to change the `version.startsWith` to `version.includes`, which has been fixed. Now, a couple of lines further down, change 'YES' to true… A never ending story 

Comment: had to change it in the community package, worked, thanks

Answer (score 34):

There is no iPhone X simulator on your machine, most probably because you updated Xcode. You can simply pass the name of the available simulator like below:

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 11"
```

For checking available simulators you can open Xcode and check on device list as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Open the file /node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js

!version.startsWith('iOS') - > !version.**includes**('iOS')

Answer (score 10):

After I updated Xcode to version 11, I encountered the same problem.

A solution can be to add the iPhone X simulator into your list.

- Choose simulator -> Hardware -> Manage Devices (you will see a popup)
- Choose "Simulators" -> (left bottom corner) +(the plus icon, next to "Filter") then add a new simulator,
- Simulator Name: iPhone X
  Device Type: Choose iPhone X.

It worked for me

Comment: This is the proper 2019 solution 

Comment: Definitely the way to go. Ran into 2 small issues tho:

1- Had to pair my new "iPhone X" simulator with an iOS 12.4 runtime
2- Had to replace `simulator.isAvailable !== 'YES'` with `simulator.isAvailable !== true` in `node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js`

Answer (score 9):

I also did not have iPhone X installed as a simulator on Xcode.  All I had to do was add the iPhone X as a new simulator in Xcode and all is well.

In Xcode: Go to `Window` then `Devices and Simulators`.  Click the simulators tab.  Click the `+` button on the bottom left corner and add the iPhone X.

I hope this fix is as easy for you as it was for me.

Comment: It's as easy as this, at least for me.

Answer (score 8):

I encountered the same error when i upgraded my Xcode 10 to Xcode 11, But specifying the simulator version happens to be a quick fix for me.

First list all available ios emulator with

```
  xcrun simctl list devices | grep iPhone | grep -v unavailable | cut -d'(' -f1
```

Result
[image: Output]

Then select one to run react-native with, e.g

```
 react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 11 Pro Max'
```

Comment: this should work I think but did not for me, I tried with the relevant simulator open and closed

Answer (score 6):

For Xcode 11.2 and iOS 13.2 here are changes i've done to run the app in simulator

in `findMatchingSimulator.js`

line 43:

```
if (!version.startsWith('iOS') && !version.startsWith('tvOS')) {
```

to

```
if (!version.includes('iOS') && !version.includes('tvOS')) {
```

line

line 52

```
if (
    simulator.availability !== '(available)' &&
    simulator.isAvailable !== 'YES'
  ) {
    continue;
  }
```

to

```
if (
    simulator.isAvailable != true
  ) {
    continue;
  }
```

P.S.

First day on React project ad already lowing it! (no)

Answer (score 5):

in my case i run the script:
sed -i '' 's/startsWith/includes/g' node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js
and it worked.
also suitable for people who can't update react-native

Answer (score 5):

My problem was that iPhone X simulator was not installed

You can check what simulators are installed with

```
xcrun simctl list devices | grep iPhone | grep -v unavailable | cut -d'(' -f1
```

Then run

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone Xs"
```

Answer (score 3):

easy fix...

Xcode -> preferences -> components install ios 12.2 sumulator

Comment: @velvetlnk - mine only goes up as far as

Comment: install any ios versions below 13

Answer (score 2):

if could not found simulator still persists after replacing following lines of code in runSimulator.js.

> Path for runSimulator.js ->
>   /node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js

```
if (!version.startsWith('iOS') && !version.startsWith('tvOS')) { continue; }
```

with this one

```
if ( !version.startsWith('com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS') && !version.startsWith('com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS') ) { continue; }
```

comment following lines after replacing

```
if ( simulator.availability !== '(available)' && simulator.isAvailable !== 'YES' ) { continue; }
```

It will launch iPhone simulator without any issue.

**and 2nd approach after updating to XCode 11**

Xcode 11 xcrun returns true or false and not YES or NO for **isAvailable** property as before.
You can check that using the following command

```
xcrun simctl list devices --json
```

> **above command will print all available devices** like following

```
"com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-2" : [
  {
    "state" : "Booted",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPhone X",
    "udid" : "E53748D1-628B-4A99-A419-4D7AE7CE4745"
  }
]
```

> Replace YES with  **true** in following code

```
if ( simulator.availability !== '(available)' && simulator.isAvailable !== 'YES' ) { continue; }
```

> **like this**

```
if ( simulator.availability !== '(available)' && simulator.isAvailable !== true ) { continue; }
```

Comment: Yes, that's what my issue was that after update to xcode 11 i started getting this error. replacing 'YES' with true did the job.

Answer (score 2):

change 
`/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/commands/runIOS/index.js`

file

```
options: [{
    name: '--simulator [string]',
    description: 'Explicitly set simulator to use. Optionally include iOS version between' + 'parenthesis at the end to match an exact version: "iPhone 6 (10.0)"',
    default: 'iPhone X'
  }
```

to

```
options: [{
    name: '--simulator [string]',
    description: 'Explicitly set simulator to use. Optionally include iOS version between' + 'parenthesis at the end to match an exact version: "iPhone 6 (10.0)"',
    default: 'iPhone 8'
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue after trying to upgrade React Native from `0.59.8` to `0.59.9`.

It turns out (based the above answers), we need to update `@react-native-community/cli` module:

1. Remove it from lockfile (`yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json`)
2. Run `yarn` or `npm install` to install it again.

reference: https://github.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge/issues/21#issuecomment-507645945

Answer (score 1):

With react-native-cli 2.0.1, you may want to just rename your simulator.  By default Xcode will name some devices in the format `<DeviceName> (<DeviceSize>)`.  However this version of the CLI interprets anything in parentheses as the iOS version.

When trying to run a simulator named `iPad Pro (10.5-inch)`, I was able to get it to run by simply renaming the simulator to `iPad Pro [10.5-inch]`.

You can rename simulators by using the Simulator app's  `Hardware`->`Device`->`Manage Devices...` menu, and right-clicking one of your simulators (in Xcode 10.2.1)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the issue when I updated Xcode. All the simulators were not available/uninstalled. I am installing them again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i have tried others above solution but nothing worked.

Then i try upgrading react-native from `0.59.5` to `0.59.10` then it's solved

Comment: After trying everything I changes the version from `0.59.5` to `0.59.10` and it resolved the issue, great great advice :)

Answer (score 1):

What fixed it for me was not having Xcode command lines tools set (`xcrun simctl` was failing.) If you just re-installed Xcode, you might have this issue.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63172300/5354268) on how to set the command line tools. After, try running `react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 11"` (or whatever your simulator name is).

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that after an xcode update the simulator got removed and I had to create it manually (as this new xcode Version did not had it as a default)

You could check if it is as device listed here:

```
xcrun simctl list devices
```

If it's under the "Unavailable" title (because you're missing the iOS version), you can create one with you current version, or download the expected runtime.

For that go to XCode->Window->Devices and Simulators and hit on the plus button, to create your simulator with model an iOS version as depicted here:
[image: Screenshot add Simulator]

That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to update React Native to 0.60 by running `npx react-native-git-upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

> **npm audit fix**

this worked for me

Comment: Worked in this answer too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55411403/4294399

Answer (score -1):

I'm having the same issue each time I update Xcode. 
I run this command:

```
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```

Then I run `react-native run-ios` again.

Answer (score -4):

Just reboot your computer and run command again.