# react-native run-ios can not find any simulator

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-simulator

I have been facing an issue where 'react-native run-ios' can not start, regardless of the simulator I add to the --simulator argument.
XCode has the correct location for the 'command line tools'

I am always getting the error:
Could not find iPhone X simulator

```
Error: Could not find iPhone X simulator
    at resolve (/Users/eric/.../swim/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:149:13)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at runOnSimulator (/Users/eric/.../swim/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:134:10)
    at Object.runIOS [as func] (/Users/eric/.../swim/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:106:12)
    at Promise.resolve.then (/Users/eric/.../swim/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cliEntry.js:117:22)
```

react-native info

```
>   React Native Environment Info:
>     System:
>       OS: macOS 10.14.2
>       CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-8950HK CPU @ 2.90GHz
>       Memory: 6.76 GB / 32.00 GB
>       Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
>     Binaries:
>       Node: 10.15.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
>       Yarn: 1.13.0 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
>       npm: 6.4.1 - /usr/local/bin/npm
>     SDKs:
>       iOS SDK:
>         Platforms: iOS 12.1, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.1, watchOS 5.1
>     IDEs:
>       Android Studio: 3.1 AI-173.4819257
>       Xcode: 10.1/10B61 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
>     npmPackages:
>       react: 16.6.3 => 16.6.3 
>       react-native: 0.57.8 => 0.57.8 
>     npmGlobalPackages:
>       create-react-native-app: 1.0.0
>       react-native-cli: 2.0.1
>       react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've found a temporary fix:

In the following file:

```
/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js
```

...change line 42 to:

```
if (!version.startsWith('com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS') && !version.startsWith('tvOS')) {
```

Comment: Upgraded Xcode to 10.2 today and hit this snag.  This was the fix.  Thanks!

Answer (score 30):

## Update

It is fixed in v1.9.8.

Update cli is the easy solution

```
npm install -g react-native-cli@latest
```

---

This issue is fixed but not released yet. 
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-cli/pull/274

So it can be solved temporarily to fix the file below.

```js
/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js
```

Change this line

```
if (!version.startsWith('iOS') && !version.startsWith('tvOS')) {
```

to

```
if (!version.includes('iOS') && !version.includes('tvOS')) {
```

Do not forget apply this again when you reinstall packages.

Comment: @n13 Good to help you.

Comment: Latest cli (2.0.1) still didn't work for me. Inline fix works for now :)

Comment: Great Experience with your answer.

Answer (score 6):

I tried like below

Open `Xcode`. Then `Preferences` -> Select `Components` in Tabs.

Then install any one(or more) of the available simulators on the list. Preferably the recent one at the top.

It solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm and intuitive solution.

Answer (score 5):

***Try this script from Terminal***

sed -i '' 's/startsWith/includes/g' node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js

***Now run***

```
react-native run-ios
```

Answer (score 4):

Just do

`npm install`

Then it will show warnings, then fix them by using following command

`npm audit fix`

Comment: `npm audit fix` updates all dependencies to latest version? This breaks my app too

Answer (score 1):

Here is additional temporary fix too. I am using Catalina.

I this file:

```
/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js
```

Change line 42 to:

```
if (!version.includes('iOS') && !version.includes('tvOS')) {
```

Change line 52-53 from:

```
simulator.availability !== '(available)' &&
simulator.isAvailable !== 'YES'
```

to:

```
simulator.isAvailable !== true
```

because the returned json list from command `xcrun simctl list --json devices`, the property isAvailable is boolean and didn't have property 'availability'.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the findMatchingSimulator.js in node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js.

First boot a Simulator then run xcrun simctl list --json devices and search the one with "state" : "Booted",.

Then add at the top in the findMatchingSimulator function:

```
return {
udid: <uuid from booted device>, // 'BFA2D7D0-AD49-472F-8279-585DDBBF9151'
name: <Name of the booted simulator>, //"iPhone X"
booted: true,
version: "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-1",
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by replacing line number 62 in `YourProjectFolder/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js`

This line

```
if (
        simulator.availability !== '(available)' &&
        simulator.isAvailable !== 'YES'
      ) {
```

With this one

```
if (
      !simulator.isAvailable
   ) {
```

In some case there may be some different solutions for everyone just debug findMatchingSimulator.js file by putting console.log() so you'll know why it is not detecting simulator. In my case the `xcrun simctl list devices --json` command not providing `simulator.availability` and `simulator.isAvailable` is not string it's bool.
I printed the simulator list which command is returning through the following line

```
  console.log(JSON.stringify(simulator.simulatorName));
  console.log(simulator.isAvailable);
  console.log('-------------------------------------------------------------');
```

The after running command `react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone SE"` I got output in the terminal and fixed code according to console print. And my simulator was running.

Answer (score 0):

try npm install --force if you don't want to break your app with npm audit fix