# React-native run-ios command - Could not find iphone simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Trying to run an existing react-native app using ios simulator: `react-native run-ios`

I have looked here and tried all of the helpful answers: [react-native run-ios can not find any simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54507749/react-native-run-ios-can-not-find-any-simulator)

I have also checked other github issues for react-native here: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/418 and here: https://www.bram.us/2019/09/04/react-native-could-not-find-iphone-x-simulator/ and nothing that was said has worked for me.

This is the full error log:

```
LO60188:appfolder mac$ react-native run-ios
Scanning folders for symlinks in /Users/mac/../../node_modules (10ms)
Found Xcode workspace MyAppName.xcworkspace
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Frameworks/InstrumentsPackaging.framework/Versions/A/Resources/XRPackageModel.momd/XRPackageModel 9.0.omo'

Could not find iPhone 6 simulator
```

I have ran `npm audit fix` as per suggested solutions to this, now I'm getting a build error, although the simulator runs with no app inside it.

```
The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/../../../appfolder/ios/build/CC/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ReactNativeConfig.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeConfig.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ReactNativeConfig.o /Users/../../../appfolder/node_modules/react-native-config/ios/ReactNativeConfig/ReactNativeConfig.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

I then tried a specific iphone simulator, to no avail either (same build error as above):

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone SE"
```

React native version for the project is: 0.55 but changed to 0.61.4 after running `npm audit fix`

Is it something to do with the podfile? As I had to run `pod init` and `pod install` to install the podfile

Any guidance greatly appreciated

Comment: If you have updated XCode, make sure that this simulator is available there.

Comment: Xcode CL tools is 11.2.1. Running this command: xcrun simctl list devices, all my simulators are displaying (shutdown)

Comment: Try to create a new simulator with the same name.

Comment: I have iOS 12.4 simulator downloaded and installed? I've also restarted my mac

Comment: Created a new iPhone SE simulator and it's also (shutdown)

Comment: Try to run these simulators from Xcode. I'm sure that something wrong with your simulators.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202818/discussion-between-aytek-and-cala).