# Can't run React Native on Catalina

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator

When I try to run a React Native App in the simulator, i get this:

```
Error: Could not find iPhone X simulator
    at resolve (/Users/hugh/code/iosapps/Test/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:149:13)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at runOnSimulator (/Users/hugh/code/iosapps/Test/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:134:10)
    at Object.runIOS [as func] (/Users/hugh/code/iosapps/Test/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:106:12)
    at Promise.resolve.then (/Users/hugh/code/iosapps/Test/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cliEntry.js:117:22)
```

The simulator exsists on my system, but React Native can't find it.

Please help me!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-native run-ios can not find any simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54507749/react-native-run-ios-can-not-find-any-simulator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not install React Native properly.

Answer (score 0):

This one drives me nuts too, I get it every time I update my OS. Your version of Xcode might be conflicting with your RN version.

Try a combo of some of these things:

Before you do ANYTHING make sure you have a working backup of your project

- upgrade react native project version (if possible) `react-native upgrade`
- remove node_modules and reinstall `rm -rf node_modules` then `npm i` or `yarn`
- remove your .lock files and run `npm i` or `yarn`

best of luck