# Since upgrading to Xcode 10.2 I can no longer run react-native run-ios through the cli

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-cli

I upgraded to Xcode 10.2 today, since upgrading I can't run `react-native run-ios` through the cli:

```
react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone X"

Found Xcode workspace a.xcworkspace

Could not find iPhone X simulator

Error: Could not find iPhone X simulator
    at resolve (/Users/user/Documents/work/a/a-light-ui/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:149:13)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at runOnSimulator (/Users/user/Documents/work/a/a-light-ui/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:134:10)
    at Object.runIOS [as func] (/Users/user/Documents/work/a/a-light-ui/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:106:12)
    at Promise.resolve.then (/Users/user/Documents/work/a/a-light-ui/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cliEntry.js:117:22)
```

If I run `xcrun simctl list devices` all of the simulators show `(Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)`:

```
iPhone X (7AADFA50-7B57-4A40-8434-9A86F345D7ED) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
```

Has anyone else had this issue with RN since upgrading xcode to 10.2? It still works through Xcode.. but that means opening Xcode.

Comment: this can help you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54504076/react-native-run-ios-returns-error-could-not-find-iphone-x-simulator

Comment: Try to reinstall command line tools

Comment: Try this script. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56920807/706888

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I solved like this ;

Firstly, you need to go this path

> node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js

and then;

You need to change this code

```
if (!version.startsWith('iOS') && !version.startsWith('tvOS'))
```

with

```
if (!version.startsWith('com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS') && !version.startsWith('com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS'))
```

I hope, it will be helpful,

ref : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21498#issuecomment-476621627

Comment: This works! Thanks @Abdullah K. 

Hopefully they release a proper fix soon as this means we will need to make this change every-time we run `npm install`

Comment: It is working. Also found the solution here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23282

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would add my solution here too, in hopes to help someone.  I just upgraded to Mac OS Mojave and I also upgraded to Xcode 10.2.  My whole react native project broke, real bad. So then I downgraded Xcode back to 10.1.  Then, I started to see this error, in said after running react-native run-ios:

> Could not find iPhone X simulator

the above "hack" fixed it by editing the findMatchingSimulator.js file with the updates above.

Then, react-native run-ios got farther, next error was:

> :CFBundleIdentifier, does not exist

I fixed this by:

1. cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog* <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. ./configure

Now react-native run-ios works . I hope this helps someone, this was a pain in the @ss.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed since RN `v0.58.0`, see commits [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/23305)

IIRC this bug was introduced in Xcode `10.1`

Also, you can fix this by simply replacing `startsWith()` with `includes()`. But doing this every time you update `node_modules` is less than ideal so I would recommend updating your RN version if possible.

Answer (score 0):

if could not found simulator still persists after replacing following lines of code in runSimulator.js.

> Path for runSimulator.js -> /node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/findMatchingSimulator.js

```
if (!version.startsWith('iOS') && !version.startsWith('tvOS')) { continue; }
```

with this one

```
if ( !version.startsWith('com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS') && !version.startsWith('com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.tvOS') ) { continue; }
```

comment following lines after replacing

```
if ( simulator.availability !== '(available)' && simulator.isAvailable !== 'YES' ) { continue; }
```

> **and 2nd approach after updating to XCode 11**

Xcode 11 xcrun returns true or false and not YES or NO for isAvailable property as before. You can check that using the following command

```
xcrun simctl list devices --json
```

> above command will print all available devices like following

```
 com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-2" : [
  {
    "state" : "Booted",
    "isAvailable" : true,
    "name" : "iPhone X",
    "udid" : "E53748D1-628B-4A99-A419-4D7AE7CE4745"
  }
]
```

> Replace YES with true in the following code

```
if ( simulator.availability !== '(available)' && simulator.isAvailable !== 'YES' ) { continue; }
```

like this

```
if ( simulator.availability !== '(available)' && simulator.isAvailable !== true ) { continue; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You even just do something like this

`if (version.indexOf('iOS') === -1)`...