# Error HE0046: Failed to install the app ... simctl returned exit code 72

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, xamarin.ios

When trying to run my Xamarin.iOS from Visual Studio on my Windows machine, while paired to my Mac, I get the error

> error HE0046: Failed to install the app '...' on the device 'iOS 15.4 (19E240) - iPad (9th generation)': simctl returned exit code 72

Comment: Have you solved your problem? BTW, what is your XCode version and Visual Studio version in Windows machine? Last but not least, have you set the command line tools in your Xcode like `Xcode > Preferences > Locations, Set Command line Tools`?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Thanks for your input.  I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 13):

Another time, this was fixed by

Xcode menu > Preferences… > Locations tab > Select Command Line Tools dropdown
I was asked for a password, then it all worked again.

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/54876998/270155

Comment: I have only one option already selected, but below, grayout, was a message like "no xcode selected",  then clicking a few times on the dropdown , password promt was presented, when entered the password, the  "no xcode selected" message changed to the xcode app location, and I was able to run the app.

Comment: It helped me. Also, make sure that your iPhone is in Developer mode

Answer (score 4):

Close VS, Start XCode and let XCode pairing your iPhone automatically, then close XCode and open VS, try running again.

Comment: This one did it for me!

Answer (score 1):

Start XCode on the Mac.  XCode will indicate that some tools are missing to enable debugging, and prompts you to allow it to automatically install them - allow it to do this, then try running again from Visual Studio - no restarts required.

Answer (score 0):

In xcode under window - devices and simulators, it said that it was waiting for my ipad to accept the trust, but nothing was showing on my ipad.  I shutdown the mac and restarted and went back into devices and simulators.  At that point a message did show on my ipad which I accepted then it also told me that I needed to turn on developer mode on the ipad and restart it.

I did not have to exit VS on my PC, but I did have to reconnect to the mac within VS.

After that I was able to deploy to the ipad!