# Failed to execute 'devicectl' on Release Deploy to iPhone

Tags: maui

Unfortunately, when I try to Deploy my App in Release mode to my iPhone, I do get this weird error message and I don't know how to fix this:

```xml
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       error MT1045: Failed to execute 'devicectl': 'devicectl -j /var/folders/qt/8sch5ydd6m9blhgt5sx6yt780000gn/T/tmpL5ozjb.tmp device install app --device "MAUIoxo???s iPhone" /Users/mauioxo/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/OptimizerApp/8b2a44054b86a247a6bd6cb17c46335345dd43048ad554de31a6db049b8cb60a/bin/Release/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/OptimizerApp.app' returned the exit code 1.
```

I CCleaned outputs already on the Mac and, also all my obj/bin folders and additionally cleaned my solution.

Nothing worked and I don't know what I can do. I also looked into folder `/Users/mauioxo/Library/Caches/` on my Mac, but there is no **Xamarin** folder as the message said.

Any recommendations?

Comment: May I know what is your iOS version of your iPhone and what is your XCode version in your MAC?

Comment: My iOS Version is 17.3.1 and Xcode is the latest I can get on Ventura via AppStore and should be 15.2

Comment: What I also found was a hint to the Provisioning Profile: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Unable-to-deploy-to-iphone-from-VS-2022/10523574? But, how would I check this as a reason. I already changed it last week and it worked with it. Don’t know how this would have changed to the worse automatically. Debug Deploys and execution on Simulator iPhone 15 with iOS 17.2 works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen other users getting the Error `error MT1045: Failed to execute ‘devicectl’.` when deploying to the device.

To fix it, you can try to upgrade the VS version to Version `17.8.5`. And also you can try to regenerate the provisioning profile and check it is configured correctly.

For more details, you can refer to the links below:

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/19738

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/18947

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Unable-to-deploy-to-iphone-from-VS-2022/10523574?

[Error HE0046: Failed to install the app ... simctl returned exit code 72](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74128227/error-he0046-failed-to-install-the-app-simctl-returned-exit-code-72)

Comment: I checked with Visual Studio 17.10.0 Preview 1 and 17.9 and it was the same.

Comment: Talking about Provisioning Profiles: how should it be created (the settings) when it should be possible to run on Simulator and Deploy to a real device or AppStore? Setting Options are really confusing on the Apple Pages for that. Working as an Individual. Additionally, I can also see outdated Profiles in VS for Windows and Xcode. Is there a way to delete them?

Comment: 1. Please refer to [Publish the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/publish-app-store?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=vs) and then upload the ipa to the App Store, then install the app on iPhone using TestFlight.

Comment: 2. For the outdated Profiles, you can skip it via [manual provisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=vs) or you can delete it, in Windows is under `(C:\\Users\{username}\\AppData\\Local\\Xamarin\\iOS\\Provisioning or Certificates)`, Mac is under  `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/`. You can delete it and then restart the VS and then pair to mac again. 3.Also, can you try to create a new empty project and to see if you can deploy your App in Release mode to your iPhone?

Comment: This I tried yesterday which did not work, unfortunately. So, what I wanted to check this weekend is if it is VS and maybe install a new Preview version in hope the 17.10.0 Preview got this new fix talked about in the above links. Or check if it was one of the Provisioning Profiles. When I connect my Profile in VS it just allows me to select the one that is currently selected. But anyway, I also deplored it with that a couple of days ago. Since then, there might have been a new VS Update or the update of iOS on the phone. Not sure if I have to trust again on something on the phone after that?

Comment: This thing is kidding me: today I tried again after a couple of days without success. Changed just nothing - if anything then just two things: opened Xcode on my Mac > Settings > Accounts and Downloaded Profiles again and also clicked on Manage Certificates (which I did the days before, too). Then I wen to https://developer.apple.com/account/resources to check if my Provisioning Profiles are still the same. One of them was the same as I already used, I tried to deploy and it was successful! I wondered that there were 2 Profiles - one was restored obviously and had a name I used before

Comment: @OXO Thanks for your update, glad to see it works finally.  So you may need to choose the proper Profiles to get it deployed successfully! :)

Comment: The interesting fact to see was that underneath an old Profile was restored in the Apple Plattform. But anyway, this Profile wasn't used. I used my new one. To be honest, I can't tell right now, what the single point was that helped to solve this isse. That's a bit unsatisfactory. But just wanted to mention everything so somebody else that runs into the same issue has some hints what to try. Thanks a lot for your support on that!