# Unable to find SDK Microsoft.NET.Sdk in Visual Studio for Mac 17.5 Preview

Tags: visual-studio-mac

I get this error message when I want to create a new MonoGame iOS project from a template in VS 2022 for Mac 17.5 Preview:

[image]

What is missing in Preferences? What should I install?
[image]

Comment: From the screenshot it does not seem that you have the .NET SDKs installed, only the runtimes. I first try checking for updates in Visual Studio for Mac to see if that offers to install the .NET SDKs. If that does not work try quitting Visual Studio for Mac and then installing the .NET SDKs from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download

Comment: It works now. I installed .NET 6.0 and .NET 7.0.